# Expected value, discrete random variable,discount factor

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation, game-theory

This example is taken from [HERE](http://read.pudn.com/downloads146/ebook/635671/MIT%20Press%20-%20Game%20Theory--Fudenberg%20&%20Tirole--579p.pdf)
,page 424:

What is the expected value $X(v)$ of this series: 
$X(v)=E(\Sigma_{t=0}^{\infty}\delta^t p_t(v))$ where $p_t(v)\in[0,1]$
with $\delta\in(0,1)$? Are all data needed for the expected value given?

I.e. what is the *formula* for such an expected value of a discounted series of probabilities?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $X$ has probability mass function $\{p_n\}$, i.e. $p_n\geqslant0$ for all $n$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty p_n = 1$. Let $\delta\in(0,1)$. Then the generating function of $X$ is
$$\mathbb E\left[\delta^X\right] = \sum_{n=0}^\infty p_n\delta^n. $$
For example, if $X\sim\operatorname{Pois}(\lambda)$ then
$$\mathbb E\left[\delta^X\right] = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^n}{n!}\delta^n=e^{-\lambda}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(\lambda\delta)^n}{n!} = e^{-\lambda(1-\delta)}. $$

Comment: How can $p_n=x^n(m^n,m^n,v)\in [0,1]$ imply $X(v)\leq 1$ few lines below? The $p_n$'s does not sum up to $1$ by the inequality $0\leq x^n(m^n,m^n,v) \leq 1$, but it should hold whenever this inequality is satisfied for all $n$'s.

Comment: Oh, by "discounted series of probabilities" I assumed you were specifying a probability distribution. You could always normalize by dividing by the sum of the $p_n$'s.

Comment: But I do not follow his implication just below the formula for $X(v)$: $0\leq x^n(h^n,m^n,v)\leq 1$ should *imply* that $0\leq X(v) \leq 1$, which in turn implies $\delta=0$ for the special case of $x^n(h^n,m^n,v)=1$. Is this meant by the implication that we have the discount factor $\delta=0$?This is strange.